# Sub Query with Aggregate Function in where clause not working in SOQL Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have written a very simple SOQL query in Salesforce but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT Id, UserId, TerritoryId, IsActive 
FROM UserTerritory 
WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId 
                    FROM UserTerritory 
                    GROUP BY UserId  
                    HAVING COUNT(UserId) > 1)
```

The query above is throwing the following exception:

1. In Developer Console, it shows "Unknown error parsing query"
2. In Workbench, it shows:

> MALFORMED_QUERY:  (SELECT UserId FROM UserTerritory GROUP BY
>   UserId HAVING count(UserId) ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:114 expecting a
>   right parentheses, found 'GROUP'

Answer (score 0):

Such query doesn't make sense anyway.

Let's say that you have simplified the original SOQL as follows:

```
SELECT Id, UserId, TerritoryId, IsActive 
FROM UserTerritory 
WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM UserTerritory)
```

Salesforce won't let you do so and the exception will be thrown:

```
The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type
```

If more thorough analysis is expected, additional details on the topic are needed (ideally, data examples).